# Show difference between conditional expectations is positive

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose we have a continuous random variable $Y$ and a random Bernoulli variable $T$ such that $P(T=1|Y)$ is monotonically increasing in $Y$.

How can we show that $E[Y|T=1]>E[Y|T=0]$?

To me, it makes intuitive sense, but I can't prove it mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to answer the question myself. I'm including the solution here for other people that might have the same question.

I want to show that the quantity below is greater than $0$.

$=E[Y \mid T = 1]-E[Y \mid T = 0]$

$=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{yP(Y=y \mid T=1)dy}    -\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{yP(Y=y \mid T=0)dy}$

Let $p = P(T=1)$ and $f$ be the PDF of $Y$. Then:

$=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{y\left(\frac{P(T=1 \mid Y=y)f(y)}{p}-\frac{(1-P(T=1 \mid Y=y))f(y)}{1-p}\right)dy}$

$=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f(y)y\left(\frac{P(T=1 \mid Y=y) - p}{p(1-p)}\right)dy}$

$=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f(y)y P(T=1 \mid Y=y)dy}  -   p\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f(y)ydy})$

Let $Z=P(T=1 \mid Y)$. Then:

$=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}(E[YZ]  -   E[Z]E[Y])$

$=\frac{1}{p(1-p)}Cov(Y,Z)$

We know that $Z$ is increasing in $Y$, and the covariance of a random variable and an increasing function of that random variable is always positive ([see reference](https://www.math.tu-dresden.de/sto/schmidt/dsvm/dsvm2003-4.pdf)). Therefore:

$=E[Y \mid T = 1]>E[Y \mid T = 0]$